# Drawboard PDF: PageUp/Down Without Zooming Out

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, pdf

When using <kbd>PageUp</kbd> or <kbd>PageDown</kbd> in Drawboard PDF, the viewer also zooms all the way out, if I am zoomed into a document. Is there a way to use <kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd> without zooming all the way out? (**Note**: This excludes using <kbd>ArrowDown</kbd>/<kbd>ArrowUp</kbd> to scroll through a page.)

Comment: Indeed, very annoying!

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by locking the zoom. The option is available once you left click on the zoom size, as if your trying to adjust the size by text. With that you can scroll through pages without it restarting the zoom.